# Overhead of pintool with no instrumentation done

Tags: c++, instrumentation, intel-pin

I observe almost 50% overhead with some frontend bound microbenchmarks even though I don't instrument the code. There are no callbacks and the pintool just attaches to the microbenchmark using its PID. What is causing this overhead? Is there a way to overcome it? Thanks!

I tried removing all callbacks. Essentially the pintool attaches to the benchmark using its PID and doesn't instrument anything.
Vtune says Pincrt is consuming a lot of time.

[EDIT]
This is Vtune threading bottom-up snapshot. Here, I am attaching pintool to a game binary.
[Bottom-up Vtune](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpBpH.png)
[Function that takes the most time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u89MX.png)

Comment: Don't forget that Intel PIN is - by default - a JIT DBI (Just In Time Dynamic Binary Instrumentation), so as soon as PIN is attached to the binary, the latter is JIT-ed, whether you have instrumentation callbacks or not. If you want less impact on the execution, use the PIN's "probe mode" (the binary is not JIT-ed anymore, it is executed, and your callbacks are native code redirected through native trampolines). Probe mode comes with its own drawbacks though (it's harder to work with, you have less leeway to set the probes and what the latter can do compared to JIT mode).